# querying in oracle table too slow

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Application i worked on has a user `search API` which will do a user search based on `Name,Address,DateOfBirth,and Pincode`. Of these only `pincode` is the `mandatory` field. And any 2 of `other data (Date of birth, address, name)` can be send. Also in one request clients can search for multiple users. So against each search key we have to give response like either found `USER` object or `NOT FOUND` response.

This is how our algorithm works for each search keys .

1. Fetch all the user profile from table with the given pincode.
2. Iterate users from step 1 and check if any two of date of birth,
   name, address  matches then that is a valid candidate. We are doing
   this using predicate as shown below

> stream(profiles.spliterator(), false).filter(new
>       UserSearchPredicate(key)).
>
> This predicate will check if any 2 of the
>       values matched and if yes return true.

3. Check if only one user we got from step 2 then DONE. Otherwise Exception
4. Return user.

The above algorithm has a problem , it is searching the users table by pincode. 
Total 20 million records are there in the table which makes the query slow. AGainst one pincode we may get 16000 or more records , iterating it is another bottle neck area. ALso this has to be done for all search keys. There can be 50 or more search keys in one request, which took almost a minute to respond.

What we have done:

Pincode column indexing is properly DONE in database. We are using `oracle` DB. Also tried `parallel` processing as well. Parallel processing has a problem with `DB connections in connection pool` which is not a solution we concluded.

Adding one more column to the query is not logically possible because if i add name , then `where pincode='' and name=''` will be the `query`. But the matching record can be pincode and date of birth . Apart from pincode nothing is mandatory.

Question: Is there a better way to handle this problem.Am particularly looking for a better `algorithm`. please help.

Comment: well, a simple option could be to run different queries depending on the number of parameters specified with the downside of bad maintainability.Adding one more column is logically possible and quite simple, a common approach used to be to have the filter clause like WHERE :pincode = tbl.pincode AND (:searchAddress IS NULL OR :searchAddress = tbl.address) ... and so on. But this all needs to be really analyzed from DB performance perspective. As for the parallel search, if data fetching from DB into java is not the main concern (which is I believe), then processing in parallel is simple too

Comment: Consider indexing the search fields seperately from your database, for example using Hibernate Search: https://hibernate.org/search/